# ZF2 SlmQueue email notification queue

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, queue

I have to send a lot of html email-notifications with dynamic content at 10 o'clock in a ZF2 application. The content of the mails is generated on the fly at this time. I would like to use the SlmQueue module as job queue system, but I don't know really how to handle it.

- Do I have to create several jobs for generating and sending the
  mails?
- Do I have to store the whole html of the email in the job
  payload?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You haven't shown much effort in investigating these questions yourself. I suggest starting with the very good [documentation](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueue/tree/master/docs).

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at implementing two types of jobs:

1. GenerateEmailJob - This job's payload contains whatever parameters you need to successfully generate the body of the email (at the very least).  Depending on the capabilities of your mail library, you might want to generate the entire message (including headers, etc).  The job itself generates the mail content and stores it somewhere (disk, redis, a table in an RDBMS, etc).  Once the mail content is stored it creates a SendEmailJob, and sticks it on another queue.
2. SendEmailJob - This job's payload contains whatever information is needed to actually send the email, including some reference to the content generated by the GenerateEmailJob.

With those two job types, and two queues, you can then tune the number of workers for each to maximize your throughput.

I would not recommend storing the email content itself in the SendEmailJob payload.  It's a good general rule to keep job payloads as light as possible.  Instead of storing the content, you're almost always better off storing a filename, redis key, or other appropriate identifier.

Further, I've had some experience with SlmQueue, and I suggest you consider doing without.  The supported queue back-ends are different enough that you don't really get much from the abstraction.  You'd probably be better off talking directly to beanstalk, or rolling your own queue with redis, etc.

Comment: were you able to implement slmqueue in zf2 ? I tried but didn't succeed. Could you please share the code ?